# Problema ao enviar informações da View para o Controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, mvc

Estou fazendo um CRUD simples em ASP.Net MVC e implementei uma caixa de busca para procurar um produto no banco de dados. Porém quando clico em pesquisar, o item da ViewModel passado nas TagHelpers não são enviadas para o controlador. O que pode estar acontecendo?

Rodei a aplicação no modo Debug e o valor da propriedade "Search" fica sempre nulo, fazendo a checagem se o valor e nulo é retornando NotFound().

Código da View:

```
 @model WebStorageMVC.ViewModels.ProductViewModel

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Products", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="form-group search">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Search)
            <label asp-for="Search">Search</label>
            <input asp-for="Search" type="text" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-light" asp-action="Index" value="Go!" />
        </div>
    }
```

Código do Controller:

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IProductRepository _productRepository;
        private readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository;

        public ProductsController(IProductRepository productRepository, ICategoryRepository categoryRepository)
        {
            _productRepository = productRepository;
            _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ProductViewModel viewModel = new ProductViewModel();
            viewModel.Products = _productRepository.Products;
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(ProductViewModel viewModel)
        {
            string search = viewModel.Search;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            IEnumerable<Product> products = _productRepository
                .Products
                .Where(product => product.Name.Contains(search))
                .ToList();

            var productViewModel = new ProductViewModel
            {
                Products = products,
                Categories = _categoryRepository.Categories
            };

            return View(productViewModel);
        }
```

Código da ViewModel:

```
 public class ProductViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public string Search { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Em vez de `@Html.HiddenFor()`, não tinha que ser `@Html.TextBoxFor()`?

Comment: Não deu certo também :(, está chegando nulo...

Comment: Tirou o `<input asp-for="Search" type="text" />`?

Comment: Troque o nome da propriedade `Product` na View Model para outra coisa diferente do nome do tipo dela, por exemplo, `MyProduct`. Mesma coisa para `Category`, `MyCategory`. Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23642947/10991202

Comment: Sim retirei o <input>, mas mesmo assim sem sucesso novamente, mesmo renomeando

Comment: Na declaração do método HttpPost, troque de `public IActionResult Index(ProductViewModel viewModel)` para `public IActionResult Index([FromBody] ProductViewModel viewModel)`

Comment: Ainda sem sucesso... estou quebrando a cabeça aqui.

Comment: Não sei se você tem algum tipo com o nome `ViewModel`; se tiver, tente trocar o nome do parâmetro na declaração do método, de `public IActionResult Index(ProductViewModel viewModel)` para, talvez, `public IActionResult Index(ProductViewModel vm)`. Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10749502/10991202

Comment: Coloquei <form class="form-group search" asp-action="Index" method="post"> e resolveu. Obrigado ;)

Comment: Mas agora estou querendo colocar o **asp-validation-for** mas não está validando